# Confusion about combinatorial identity $k {n\choose k} = n{ {n-1}\choose{k-1} }$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Confusion about combinatorial identity $k {n\choose k} = n{ {n-1}\choose{k-1} }$

I saw this combinatorial proof in other posts about this identity. For the left hand side, we can say this is the number of ways to pick a team of $k$ people and then choose one of them to be the captain.

For the right hand side, we can say first pick the captain out of $n$ people, then there are ${n-1}\choose k-1$ ways to pick the rest of the team.

However, for the right hand side, what if we thought of the  choice in the opposite direction: first pick $k-1$ regular teammates out of $n$ options, then choose the captain. Since we have already chosen $k-1$ people, there are only $n-(k-1)$ options remaining for the captain, so we would have ${n\choose {k-1}}  (n-k+1)$, which is different from both sides of the identity.

What is wrong with the second interpretation of the right hand side? Choosing the non-captain teammates first then choosing the captain seems equivalent to choosing the captain first then choosing the non-captain teammates.

Comment: Looks good to me.  Indeed, $k\binom nk=k\times \frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac {n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$ while $(n-k+1)\times \binom n{k-1}=(n-k+1)\times \frac {n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}=\frac {n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$

Comment: "*which is different from both sides of the identity*"  Yes.  This identity could be expanded to have three, four, five... however many "sides" as you can come up with different expressions for.  You happened to find a "third" side.  That doesn't mean that the original two sides are invalid, but it does mean that your observation doesn't directly help prove the originally stated identity.

Comment: $1+1=2$.  "*But what if we subtracted $1$ from $3$?*"  Yes... $3-1=2$ as well.  What is your point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second interpretation, you wrote "pick $k-1$ regular teammates out of **n** options," but the RHS is actually ${n-1}\choose k-1$ not $n\choose{k-1}$. It's small things like that which make the difference.

Edit: I misread your question; see @lulu's comment, they are algebraically the same.